# error while installing arabic language pack in moodle website

Tags: moodle, arabic-support

[image: this is the error message]

i need to install and run the arabic language , i try to run the website after i installing the pack , and the arabic language option is shown , but when i am choosing the arabic language the website is ben stuck and not open , and after 5 minute , the website run again in english language , and if i trying to choose arabic again , the same thing happened

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the locale on the web server, this is separate from Moodle. The locale is used for dates.

The Moodle Arabic language pack uses the locale `ar_SA.utf8` - you can find this in `[yourmooodledatafolder]/lang/ar/langconfig.php`

The install depends on the server

eg: for Ubuntu use something like this

```
sudo locale-gen ar_SA
sudo locale-gen ar_SA.UTF-8
sudo update-locale
```

Then use this to check the locale is installed

```
locale -a
```

Or you could use this to install all locales

```
sudo apt install locales-all
sudo locale-gen
```

See https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/Table_of_locales